# Adding a new path to a json using jq

Tags: json, path, jq

I'm new to jq and looking form assistance, how do I transform the first json format data to the "from" format, adding an extra path.

```
**From:**

{
  "v1": "9.0.19",
  "v2": "9.0.52",
  "t2": "9.3.2",
  "t3": "9.3.2",
  "x": "9.0.46"
}

**To**


{
      "new_v1": {
          "v1": "9.0.19",
          "v2": "9.0.52",
          "t2": "9.3.2",
          "t3": "9.3.2",
          "x": "9.0.46"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jq '{"new_v1": .}' from.json
```

or even just:

```
jq '{new_v1: .}' from.json
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, didn't realize it was that easy.